# there is no clear:top;?

Tags: css

There is NO clear:top :( so I was wondering if there is a clear solution for that:

```
<div style="clear:right;float: right;">right</div>
<div style="clear:right;float: right;">right</div>
<div style="clear:right;float: right;">right</div>
<div style="clear:right;float: right;">right</div>
<div style="clear:left;float: left;">I want this to be on TOP left side without using div nor margin minus</div>
```

live example :

http://jsfiddle.net/puaction/qS7v2/

so the left div will be on the left side BUT on top not on bottom WITHOUT using div nor minus margin.

You can see exactly why I need it so badly here :

http://pua.puaction.com/

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do here. Perhaps create an image of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to render your div before any divs that have floats to the right.

In this case :

```
<div style="clear:left;float: left;">I want this to be on TOP left side without using div nor margin minus</div>
<div style="clear:right;float: right;">right</div>
<div style="clear:right;float: right;">right</div>
<div style="clear:right;float: right;">right</div>
```

And on your website you should place `div#sliderwrap` before `div#boxreg`

Comment: Yes I know that BUT I need to place some other div's IN BETWEEN and I want them also to be on the top of the left side *below* the last left div. Any Ideas ? (I don't want to use divs nor margin minus)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to drinchev answer, it's a better practice to use inline-block (instead of float), for clear look for "clear fix".